# How to iterate through the 'For' loop only after completion of ajax calls in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, ajax, for-loop

I have a sample code where I have a for loop inside which I have a function to make an `ajax` call to fetch data. I am facing an issue here where I need the iteration to take place only after the completion of `ajax` call. What is happening is the iteration is getting completed and even the statements after the loop is getting executed and only then the `ajax` call is getting completed.

> Actual Result -
>   Loop 1 Initiation,
>   Loop 1 Completion,
>   Statement outside loop execution,
>   Ajax Call completion.
>
> Expected Result - 
>   Loop 1 Initiation,
>   Ajax call completion,
>   Loop 1 completion,
>   Statement outside loop execution.

We can see in the that the output of the following sample code the value of  $scope.finalData is empty as the data assignment took place before completion of the ajax call.

```
<html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="x in finalData">
                    {{ x.Name + ', ' + x.Country }}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <script>
            var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
            app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
                $scope.myData = [];
                for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
                    console.log('before '+i+'execution');
                    $http.get("https://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php").then(function (response) {
                        $scope.myData = response.data.records;
                        console.log('Inside loop - data'+response.data.records);
                    });
                    console.log('Outside loop - data'+$scope.myData);
                    console.log('after '+i+'execution'); 
                }
                $scope.finalData = $scope.myData;
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have also updated the code in the plunker - https://plnkr.co/edit/XyRVeY5WuUT6ZEKOjc2M?p=preview

Comment: `$http` is an asynchronous callback, you can't expect it to arrive in between your logs. You can do all the processing in `$http.get(...).then(/* here */).finally(/* or here */)`. If you want to do multiple `$http` calls, then use `$q` as: `$q.all(promises)` by appending it with `promises.push($http.get(...).then( return ...; ))`

Comment: the solution is not to use a loop for this at all. Maintain `i` as a counter yourself. When i = 0 make the first ajax call. Then when that call completes, increment i to 1 and make the next call, etc until you have finished. Obviously you'll want to have the code which makes the call encapsulated in a function which accepts `i` (and anything else it needs) as input parameters, otherwise you'll massively repeat your code.

Comment: @Alexksey Solovey Yeah actually tried those already. This is just an illustration of my actual problem. Consider we need to iterate through an array and send the values as the query string. I could use $q.all(promises). But I need some other independent statements outside for loop to be executed only after the for loop completion which should get completed only after the ajax calls.

Comment: `$q.all` _is_ outside of for loop, you can retrieve your results (all of them) with: `$q.all(promises).then((res) => { $scope.finalData = res; }).finally( /* any other asynchronous processing goes here */ );`

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is you're expecting an asynchronous call (the ajax request) to behave synchronously (halt until it completes). What actually happens is that `$http.get` *immediately* returns with a promise, and your `for` loop continues to completion without delay. Subsequently the promise eventually resolves *after* all that synchronous code completes, resulting in the undesired execution order you describe.

Perhaps consider an alternative approach where you first use a loop (or `map`) to generate a list of promises (each representing a separate ajax request), then use `$q.all` to ensure they are all resolved before further execution (as shown [here](https://www.martin-brennan.com/using-q-all-to-resolve-multiple-promises/) for instance).